# TFS, NuGet, Package Restore Finding projects that needs to be updated?

Tags: tfs, nuget

So the past few days i've been setting up NuGet, making packages of our internal libraries, updating our projects, getting our TFS Build server to Build. all of this is awesome! Now I have a problem though, before NuGet and package restore I could search TFS for the .dll files, as an example I could search for Company.Common.dll in TFS and find all projects that utilized this dll with the following command:

> tf dir "$/*Company.common.dll" /recursive
>   /server:http://tfs-server:8080

Now after we have started using NuGet and using package restore the dll file Company.Common.dll will not be present in TFS in the projects that uses it. that means I can't use the above search command to find the .dll file I want to update

I was contemplating writing a powershell script that would find all packages.config files in TFS and download them to a folder structure indicating where in TFS the different projects are located. Then I would traverse the packages.config file to figure out what projects used the specific NuGet package I wanted to update.

The reason for this is ofcourse that all our projects should have the Common.dll updated when there is an update too it.

What I would like to know is if anyone has already solved this "problem", so I don't have to invent the wheel again, or perhaps have some perspective or constructive comments on this. I guess the core question is this:

How do you handle updating a package across ALL projects, when there are multiple teams that create / update projects in TFS?

Comment: I could use something like this as well.  I like the PowerShell script idea, too.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the "repositoryPath" NuGet config settings and make it point to a central UNC share. More details here @ http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1.

You can use NuGet.exe Update packageName -RepositoryPath xxx -Source xxx command to update the specific package if needed.